# SELECT count from a large query, rows from a paged subset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that currently is doing something like this

```
 CREATE TABLE #results (col1 varchar(10), col2 varchar(10), col3 varchar(10), MaxRows BigInt)

 WITH Result AS (
     -- very complex query, lots of filters based on proc parameters
     SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 
     FROM BaseTable
 , TempCount AS (
     SELECT Count(*) AS MaxRows FROM Result
 )
 INSERT INTO #results (Col1, Col2, Col3, MaxRows)
 SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
 FROM Result
 OFFSET @pagenumber * @pagesize  ROWS FETCH NEXT @pagesize ROWS ONLY;

 SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM #results;

 RETURN (SELECT TOP 1 MaxRows FROM #results);
```

The desire is to return up to `@pagesize` rows, and no more, but to have the procedure return value be the total number of rows in the complex select. `@pagesize` is a parameter to the stored procedure, as is `@pagenumber`.

To add some concreteness, the actual query selecting rows from an orders table for use in filling a grid on a web page. The customer very likely has hundreds or thousands of orders. Returning all those rows to the application would be wasteful, as the application can only display one page full at a time. But the application needs to know *how many orders* are available, so it can put the proper number of "next page" links at the bottom of the grid.

The only way we were able to think of was to use a temporary table. We insert the single page of results into the temporary table while also counting the full count of results into the MaxRows column. Then once it's in the temporary table, we can select the rows from the temporary table as the resultset, and the MaxRows column as the procedure return value.

Is there a way to do this without the temporary table? If we were returning the full resultset, then I know `@@ROWCOUNT` could be an option. But we want to only return one page worth of rows.

Comment: I am not sure why do you this to insert `OFFSET @pagenumber * @pagesize  ROWS FETCH NEXT @pagesize ROWS ONLY;`

Comment: Can you please elaborate your ask?

Comment: The `OFFSET @pagenumber * @pagesize ROWS FETCH NEXT @pagesize ROWS ONLY;` is, obviously, to make it so the resultset only returns `@pagesize` rows at a time. The procedure is called repeatedly to get one page full of rows. The application is massively multitenant, and the number of columns is enormous -- caching the entire, unpaged resultset is not an option.

Comment: @TheGameiswar - Can you please elaborate your question? I don't understand what information you think is lacking.

Comment: I am not able to understand this `It wants to return only @pagesize rows as the resultset, but it wants to return the full count of rows as the return value. Therefore it uses a temporary table` but that's me

Comment: Hopefully my explanation makes more sense to you now.